# Invert the order of a list of 200 paragraphs

Tags: javascript, php, sorting

I have a list of events sorted by date and each event is within a `<p>`. There is more that 200 and it looks like this (I already managed to clean it up a little bit) :

```
<p><strong>1 july 2011</strong> event 1<br>
Place where the event 1 takes place<br>
more infos about event 1<br>
event more infos about event 1</p>
<p><strong>2 september 2011</strong> event 2<br>
Place where the event 2 takes place<br>
more infos about event 2<br>
event more infos about event 2</p>
<p><strong>3 september 2011</strong> event 3<br>
Place where the event 3 takes place<br>
more infos about event 3<br>
event more infos about event 3</p>
```

They are currently sorted by date (the oldest event first) and what I would like to do is to invert the order to have the newest events first.

The only marker I have is the `<p>` where each event is encapsuled in. Dates are not always the same format.

I've tried things with excel, notepad++ and his regex, but there is maybe something to do with PHP and/or JS ?

Can you guys help me with this one ?

Thanks !

Comment: get all of the paragraphs you need into an array and then run an array reverse function on them before re-outputting, or walk through the array backwards and output.  Using that information, you can put together some code and we can help when you have issue.

Comment: How are you painting the data? In that code, you can add an ordenation method, very simply but with the code you share is impossible to help you. We are blindness here.

Comment: Your answers made me think about an explode method, with preg_match_all function. I'll give it a try. Thanks !

Comment: where is the list coming from? Is it hardcoded in html or it is generated by a DB query?

Comment: From a doc file first, then cleaned through notepad++ and regex's.

Answer (score 2):

Well in javascript you can just read in each of the paragraphgs and then iterate over them in reverse order. Is this the kind of thing you were after.

```
  $(function() {

  var paras = $('#container p');
  var newhtml = "";
  for(var i=paras.length-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
      newhtml += $(paras[i]).html() + "</br>";
  }
  $('#container').html(newhtml);
});
```

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7yavomjs/)

Comment: programmatic solution

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sometimes things are simple but you need to explain to others to find the solution. So there it is.

```
$string = "<p>blablabla</p><p>blablabla 2</p>";
$text = str_replace('</p>', '', $string);
$array = explode('<p>', $text);
$array = array_reverse($array);
```

So simple !

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do with reg-exp:

```
$a = '<p><strong>1 july 2011</strong> event 1<br>
Place where the event 1 takes place<br>
more infos about event 1<br>
event more infos about event 1</p>
<p><strong>2 september 2011</strong> event 2<br>
Place where the event 2 takes place<br>
more infos about event 2<br>
event more infos about event 2</p>
<p><strong>3 september 2011</strong> event 3<br>
Place where the event 3 takes place<br>
more infos about event 3<br>
event more infos about event 3</p>';

$a = str_replace("\n","", $a); // maybe you dont need this line it happened to me couse of copy-paste from your question text
preg_match_all("/\<p\>(.*)\<\/p\>/U", $a, $m);

var_dump(array_reverse($m[1]));
```